# Accessing the value of the intersection of named ranges of an Excel spreadsheet in Python using xlrd?

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

In Excel VBA, you can use the Intersect function which returns a range object that is the intersection of the arguments. You can then get a value from that like so.

```
Intersection("Name1", "Name2").Value
```

In a standard cell formula you can do the same thing:

```
=Name1 Name2
```

How do I accomplish this using xlrd? I've tried reading through the Name class and area2d looks like what I'll be using, but I don't know how to tie this all together.

Comment: Are the ranges that you want to intersect rectangular, or can they be of any shape?

Comment: They are rectangular. For my purposes they are either one row in height and multiple columns in width, or one column in width and multiple rows in height. The only intersections I care about are when one of each of these cross and intersect at only one cell.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `xlrd` does not natively support this kind of intersection functionality. For the kinds of rectangular ranges that you describe, you can fairly easily calculate the intersection though, using the `Name` class, like you already suggested yourself.

The `xlrd-0.9.0` distribution that I use with `Python 2.7.2` has a directory `examples` that shows how to work with named ranges. It comes with the file `namesdemo.xls` which is a workbook from an older version of Excel (it says version `97-2004`).

An example of using that file to determine the cells in a range called `Sales` is as follows:

```
>>> import xlrd
>>> book=xlrd.open_workbook('namesdemo.xls')
>>> nameObj = book.name_and_scope_map.get(('sales', -1))
>>> nameObj.area2d()[1:5]
(1, 2, 1, 14)
>>> nameObj.result.text
u'Sheet3!$B$2:$N$2'
```

You can parse that last result to obtain the rectangle of cells in your range, or use the elements `[1:5]` from the tuple returned by the `area2d()` function -- they represent `rowxlo`, `rowxhi`, `colxlo` and `colxhi` of the rectangle. Do the same thing for another range and then you can intersect them "manually".

Note the lower-case name `'sales'` in the call to `name_and_scope_map.get()`. That is required because Excel does not have case-sensitive range names. The `-1` parameter indicates that it should search for the name globally, on all sheets.

If saved in the newer Excel `.xlsx` format, the `Name` object seems to behave slightly differently:

```
>>> book=xlrd.open_workbook('namesdemo.xlsx')
>>> nameObj = book.name_and_scope_map.get(('sales', -1))
>>> nameObj.formula_text
u'Sheet3!$B$2:$N$2'
```

In this case, I have not found any way to get access to any actual coordinates via `area2d()`:

```
>>> nameObj.area2d()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/xlrd/book.py", line 291, in area2d
    self.dump(self.book.logfile,
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'logfile'
```

so it looks like you would need to parse the `formula_text` string or check out the source code of `xlrd` to see if you can fix it :-)

The example script `xlrdnameAPIdemo.py` gives some more explanations, for example about how to look for named ranges in a particular scope/worksheet.